# Why does this semi-colon cause a incorrect falsey result

Tags: javascript, truthiness

Strange truth test results

```
filter = /rob/gi
>> /rob/gi
filter.test('hey')
>> false
filter.test('rob')
>> true
true && filter.test('rob');
>> false
true && filter.test('rob') ;
>> true
(true && filter.test('rob'));
>> false
(true && filter.test('rob')) ;
>> true
```

Reproducible in Firefox and Chrome

Comment: Remove the `g` flag and everything works as expected.

Comment: No reason to ever use a `g` flag with `.test()`.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the semicolons. Just repeat the same test multiple times and you'll see the same behavior.

Comment: OH WOW, YES! I feel like I should change the question title now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `.test` behaves as `.exec()` and maintains state (position) between calls

> As with exec() (or in combination with it), test() called multiple times on the same global regular expression instance will advance past the previous match.

So for the `'rob'` input it matches it. Then on the second call it tries to match whatever left after the first match: it's an empty string, so it fails and rewinds.

To see it in action try to match `'robrobrob'` - there will be 3 `true` followed by `false`.

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

**UPD**:

- In this particular case it happens because you use the `g` modified (credits to [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar))

Comment: You should mention that this is specifically because of the `g` modifier.